# iOS: Splitting NSString into FilePath&Name + Extension

Tags: ios, string, split, filepath, file-type

iOS: Splitting NSString into FilePath&Name + Extension

How do I split

```
@"blah/.../myfile.txt"
```

into

```
@"blah/.../myfile"
```

and

```
@"txt"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
NSString* fileName = [fileString stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString* extension = [fileString pathExtension];
```